# ASP.NET allow access to all domain users without over-riding Environment.UserName

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, integrated-security

- I have a vb.Net app which has been running fine locally using localhost and 'Integrated Security=True' in my connection string.
- The application itself uses Environment.UserName to allow access to the webpages and present different info depending on the user name I get back.

The site is now on the production server (which is still within our network) and I get 'Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVERNAME'.

I need away of allowing access to all company users and don't want to specify a user name and password in my connection string as when I do that it prevents me accessing the individual user using 'Environment.UserName' Not sure about the semantics of calling this an intranet application but I think that the area I am involved in.. Certainly the site will not be available outside the company.

I think this question needs more info but not quite sure what else to say! Will keep a close eye on any responses.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.UserName` gets you the current logged in user on the server operating system, and in ASP.NET that is the user name of the Application Pool.

In ASP.NET you should use [`HttpContext.Current.Session.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want the name of the user connecting to your website.

Comment: @Arthur: need more help?